# I want to change rows in oracle

Tags: oracle

in oracle, I want to change list of row.
so i used delete list and insert list. so it run two query.
is it best way for change rows? or some query for change list that occur to run only one query?
additionally key and number of row is different.

example..

```
TABLE#1
IDX /  NAME 
1   /  JOHN
2   /  BRIAN
```

PIDX OF TABLE #2 Is foreign key that is referenced by IDX of TABLE#1

```
TABLE#2
IDX /PIDX /ITEM
1   /1    /2399
2   /1    /1211
3   /1    /4012
4   /1    /3203
5   /2    /3211
6   /2    /2323
```

in this case, i want change to this result
and don't care IDX OF TABLE#2

```
TABLE#2
IDX /PIDX /ITEM
1   /1    /1247
2   /1    /5751
3   /2    /3211
4   /2    /2323
```

Comment: Examples give questions more substance ..

Answer (score 0):

How about using an "UPDATE" statement ?